# Number of ways to split a list of elements, such that no sublist has more than 2 elements.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a list of 4 elements : [a,b,c,d].  There are 5 ways to split this list, with no rearranging such that no sublist has more than two elements:

[a,b,c,d],[ab,c,d],[ab,cd],[a,bc,d] and [a,b,cd].

In general, with n elements, how can one count the number of ways to split a list?  This is quite similar to the stars and bars problem; however, we have distinguishable stars, but indistinguishable bins.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(n)$ denotes the number of ways of such splittings of $n$ elements set, then note that given $a_1,\ldots , a_n$ in any splitting either $a_1$ is alone or is paired with $a_2$. In first case number of splittings of remaining $n-1$ terms will be $f(n-1)$ in second case number of splittings of remaining $n-2$ terms will be $f(n-2)$. Therefore $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ for $n\geq 3$ , $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$.